# How to apply Indexable ListView with Custom Array Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to apply the Indexable ListView that I found in Github: https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView. But my problem is how can I implement it in Custom ArrayAdapter?. I'm using firebase, and I want to show my data in a listview, but my problem is I also want to implement it with Indexable ListView but I can't because there's something error when I implement it because it says not compatible. Is there any method so that I can implement Indexable ListView in my program?

Here's the portion of my code :

```
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            bookList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot bookSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Book books = bookSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);
                bookList.add(books);
            }
            BookList adapter = new BookList(getActivity(),bookList);
            ViewBook.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

BookList.java - the Custom ArrayAdapter

```
public class BookList extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {
private Activity context;
private List<Book> bookList;
private List<Image> imageList;
private ImageView image;

public BookList(Activity context, List<Book> bookList){
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout,bookList);
    this.context=context;
    this.bookList=bookList;
    this.imageList=imageList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View listViewItem= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null,true);
    TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    TextView textViewAuthor = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewAuthor);
    image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById((R.id.ivUploadImage));
    Book books  = bookList.get(position);


    textViewTitle.setText(books.getBookTitle());
    textViewAuthor.setText(books.getAuthorName());
    Picasso.with(context).load(books.getBookImageUrl()).into(image);

    return listViewItem;
}
}
```

Book.java

```
public class Book {
String bookId;
String bookTitle;
String authorName;
String bookDescription;
String bookPublisher;
String bookPages;
String bookISBN;
String bookEdition;
String bookImageUrl;


public Book() {

}

 public Book(String bookId, String bookTitle, String authorName, String 
 bookDescription,String bookPublisher, String bookPages, String bookISBN, 
 String bookEdition, String bookImageUrl) {
    this.bookId = bookId;
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    this.authorName = authorName;
    this.bookDescription = bookDescription;
    this.bookPublisher = bookPublisher;
    this.bookPages = bookPages;
    this.bookISBN = bookISBN;
    this.bookEdition = bookEdition;
    this.bookImageUrl = bookImageUrl;
}

public String getBookId() {
    return bookId;
}

public String getBookTitle() {
    return bookTitle;
}

public String getAuthorName() {
    return authorName;
}

public String getBookDescription() {
    return bookDescription;
}

public String getBookPublisher() {
    return bookPublisher;
}

public String getBookPages() {
    return bookPages;
}

public String getBookISBN() {
    return bookISBN;
}

public String getBookEdition() {
    return bookEdition;
}

public String getBookImageUrl() {
    return bookImageUrl;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the error?